# TinyMCE ol tag issues

Tags: html, list, tinymce, html-lists

I have an issue with the way TinyMCE handles and OL within an OL. There seem to be a couple of posts on this, but none that I could find answered.

So here's the issue. If you create an OL, then a sub OL within the first OL, the LI element is split to take in the second OL and closed off afterward.

```
<ol>
<li>Hi<ol style="list-style-type: lower-alpha;">
<li>There</li>
</ol></li>
</ol>
```

which then outputs something like:

```
1. Hi
   a. 1. There
```

Note the second 1 that appears.

I would have expected:

```
<ol>
<li>Hi</li>
<ol style="list-style-type: lower-alpha;">
<li>There</li>
</ol>
</ol>
```

which should output:

```
1. Hi
   a. There
```

Answer (score 0):

tinymce provides content_css property [See Here](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/configuration%3acontent_css)

with which you can apply custom style to elements you want , or rather you can use style formats [Style_Formats](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3astyle_formats) to supply it to perticular element in that instance..

hope that helps

Comment: It was quite useful yes, however, its probably more that its breaking the <li> to include an <ol> within the <li>. I wouldn't expect that would be expected, as the <li> should be closed with a <li> before another <ol>.

Like:
<ol>
<li>Something</li>
<ol>
<li>else</li>
</ol>
</ol>